# I have a bodyguard in order to protect myself

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, infinitives, stative-verbs

> I have a bodyguard **in order** to protect myself.

I was told that I cannot have a stative verb in the required condition:

> I **have** a bodyguard

But I don't understand how "I *need to study* **in order** to pass the exam" is correct when "need" is stative.

I was also told that the subject has to do the infinitive, so the following is wrong:

> **in order** to protect myself.

I was told the sentence should be written as:

> I hired a bodyguard in order to stay protected.

Is this correct, or is there no problem with my original sentence?

My question is about ***in order***.

Comment: English is quite forgiving with phraseology. Both of your sentences are fine, and I bet we could come up with 50 others just by changing clauses around and a word or two without altering the meaning or looking non-native.

Comment: Yeah! next time somebody tells you the first sentence is incorrect just look'em in the eye and say "I HAVE a bodyguard."

Comment: It seems that the "myself" itself could be out of place, since the bodyguard is the one doing the protecting, not you, and therefore, protecting one's self isn't really what is happening; "I have (or preferably hire[d]) a bodyguard (in order) to protect me." You could hire a bodyguard to protect himself, it's just kind of unconventional. I guess that as long as you _do_ have a good bodyguard, you won't get too much heckling about how you put it. :)

Comment: What you were told is mostly correct: the sentence sounds awkward because of the usual aspectual class of the verb. The "x in order to y" construction usually requires an eventive verb as x. In order for it to make sense, you have to understand it as "I got a bodyguard in order to..." (where *get* is eventive unlike stative *have*).

Comment: @jlovegren I think what the OP was told is mostly nonsense.  Do you really think "I have insurance to cover my losses" is awkward or even less preferable to "I got insurance to cover my losses"?

Comment: @deadrat I think you may have misread the question. The OP isn't asking about the infinitive. Both of your sentences sound equally natural, but "I have insurance in order to cover my losses" sounds less natural than "I got insurance in order to cover my losses."

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire Possibly.  I interpreted the question as asking about a complement for stative verbs.  It might be an infinitive of purpose ("I need **to study**) or a direct object ("I have **a bodyguard**).  I don't know how you measure "sounds natural," but "I got insurance" means something slightly different from "I have insurance," but "I've got insurance" and "I have insurance" mean the same thing.

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire The claim that the "subject has to do the  infinitive" is also nonsense.  In the example, the infinitive has an adverbial use, modifying "hired" to give the hiring's purpose.  Nothing to do with the subject.  You could say "I hired a bodyguard to protect my family."  The protecting is understood to be done by the direct object *bodyguard*), not the subject (*I*).

Comment: @deadrat I agree with you.  My comments were limited to whether _in order_ could be freely inserted into sentences where the infinitive describes the function of the object rather than the purpose of the action.  In _I have a bodyguard to protect me_, I think the infinitive describes the function of the bodyguard.  From this, it's inferred that the purpose of _I_'s having obtained the bodyguard was to protect himself. In _I have a bodyguard in order to protect myself_, it sounds strange to say the state of having a bodyguard fulfills the purpose of protecting _I_...  to me at least.

Comment: @deadrat Also, when I see _in order_ I think of steps of actions. One action is done in order to accomplish another action.  I don't really think a nonactive step can accomplish any further action.

Comment: @deadrat your example works because *have* can be coerced to have a habitual reading (something like *I maintain insurance...*). Only eventive verbs can have habitual readings according to the usual teaching about  [event classes](http://www.sfu.ca/person/dearmond/322/322.event.class.htm). The advice given to the OP is still good in general, though I don't think anyone is claiming it will work every time.

Comment: @jlovegren Coerced? What kind of talk is this?  Pretty soon you're walking around making up words like "semelfactive".  It is bad advice that instructs somebody that perfectly ordinary sentences are ungrammatical.  No fluent speaker of English will ask "Why do you have a bodyguard?", get the OP's first sentence as the answer, and say "Don't you mean you *hired* a bodyguard?"

Comment: @deadrat I'm glad you enjoyed reading about event classes. I am presuming that the OP already knows English, and just wants to know why the first sentence sounds a little odd.

Comment: @jlovegren Touché.  I actually did enjoy reading about event classes, although I'm unconvinced that such linguistic constructs really capture how the language works.  I'm just guessing, but I don't think the OP already knows English; I think the OP is learning English from people who don't know English either.

Answer (score 3):

**I'm not sure about whether your sentence is grammatical or not**, but *in order to* is usually used to express a required condition or a purpose.  You cannot fulfill a required condition by being a state.  You also cannot have a purpose behind being a state.

I think your confusion has something to do with the belief that the *to* in an infinitive can be replaced with *in order to* or *so as to*. Sometimes the to-infinitive is used to denote the function of the object but not the purpose of doing the verb.

> I have a bodyguard **to protect** me.

In this sentence, the to-infinitive is used to denote the function of the bodyguard. It, however, does not denote the purpose of doing *have* or what doing *have* is required for. In fact, it is impossible to do *have* because it is a stative verb (in this context). So, you shouldn't replace the *to* with *in order to*.

As you correctly state, in *I need to study in order to pass the exam*, *need* is a stative verb. In this context, it expresses an obligation to do the to-infinitive.  *In order to* is commonly used with such verbs (must, have, need) to emphasize that doing a verb is necessary for accomplishing something else. The meaning of your example sentence is clear: studying is necessary **to fulfill** the purpose of passing the exam.

You cannot fulfill anything (a purpose or a required condition) by doing a stative verb because you cannot do a stative verb.

Comment: What is the definition of a modal verb?

Comment: What is the definition of an auxiliary verb?

Answer (score 3):

As @deadrat mentioned in the comment, what you were told is nonsense. The linked is [a list of stative verbs](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/support-files/stative-verbs-list.pdf) that I found on the internet. The reason to classify those verbs as a stative verb is to emphasize the fact that those verbs are not (generally or usually) used in continuous (progressive) tenses as the link shows.

> I have a bodyguard in order to protect myself.

It is not grammatically incorrect. The purpose of having a bodyguard is to protect myself. It is just not as idiomatic as "I have a bodyguard to protect myself" because using **in order** could be considered **redundant**.

Let's compare the sentence with the most well-known stative verb to *be*:

> I am on a diet (in order) to lose weight.

If what you were told is right, you can't use the above sentence as to *be* is a stative verb. It is not *diet* which is to lose weight.

Using stative verb with *to infinitive* which indicates purpose is fine. But some of them may not be idiomatic. It doesn't necessarily mean you can't use to infinitive with a stative verb. You have to learn how those stative verbs are used idiomatically on a case-by-case basis.

**Edit**: To *have* is **not always a stative verb**. The most notable case is when it is used to mean to *eat* or as a causative verb, it is not a stative verb.

Let's consider the following sentences:

> I have never felt any need to have a bodyguard (in order to protect myself).
>   But sine the ISIS attacks in Paris and San Bernardino, I have just
>   decided to hire one. Now, I **have** a bodyguard (following me wherever I go 24/7) in order to protect
>   myself.

I don't think to *have* in the above sentence is a stative verb.

Comment: Nice.  Half an upvote for the quality of the answer; half an upvote for agreeing with me.

Comment: "I must study in order to pass the test" is the same as "I must study to pass the test."  In this example, the "in order" is redundant but sounds right and most (or close to most) "in order" sentences have the "must/have to/ need to... in order to" form...

Comment: @lopez11 What makes you think "I have a bodyguard in order to protect myself" doesn't sound right? Do you always have to use "must/have to/need to" to use "in order to"? What would happen to my second example? Should it be changed to "I must/have to/need to be on a diet in order to lose weight"?

Comment: It sounds weird. Both "I diet in order to lose weight" and "I am dieting in order to lose weight" are fine. But "I'm in a movie theater in order to watch a movie" doesn't feel natural. I don't know, there seems to be a split in opinions here. Again the stative thing is getting to me. As stated in the comment section, I don't think being a state can lead to accomplishing another action. At least, I don't think I've ever seen stative verbs used like that.

Comment: @lopez11 I have edited my post. Please take a look.

Comment: @lopez11 Not many people say "I diet (or am dieting) in order to lose weight". It is not idiomatic. You have a very narrow definition of a stative verb. Not all the usages of a stative verb indicate a **state**. It could indicate an **action**, too. To be on a diet is to "reduce the amount of food and calories you are taking everyday". Does "I reduce the amount of food and calories I am taking everyday in order to lose weight" make sense? Then what is the difference between "to be on a diet" and "to reduce the amount of food and calories"?

Comment: @Rathony I'm pretty sure the OP used _have_ in the stative sense (not causal). _I have a blanket to warm myself_ can't be (idiomatically) changed to _I have a blanket in order to warm myself_.  It's the same with _I have a chair (in order) to sit on._

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire The OP is saying "I have a blanket in order to warm myself" is weird while "I pulled my blanket over my body in order to warm myself" is not. The focus is on **in order**, not on whether to have is a stative verb or not.